# How to handle when there is no body data in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, vuejs2, axios

I am processing data using GetMapping in Spring Boot.

I looked up the reason and it is expected that when I call Get() in Axios, the Body data does not exist at all and I am passing it. (not empty e.g { } )

Is there any way to handle this ?

When calling json through postman, the result is as follows.
postman Get (content-type : Json)

set :

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

success case :

```js
{
  //data null
}
response : {
  status : 200
}
```

fail case :

```js
//{  --> remove brace (I didn't actually comment it out, I used it to indicate that I've removed it.)
    //data null
//}

response : 
{
  "statusCode": "ERROR",
  "status": 415,
  "message": "Content type '' not supported",
  "detailMessage": null
}
```

Comment: "Yes, you can send a request body with GET but it should not have any meaning." https://stackoverflow.com/q/978061/592355

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: so if you want to send json: put/patch/post (/...) it! ..if you want to (send data with) GET: (then,) please with (uri/path) parameters only.

Comment: a "workaraund" (let's say "hack"):  we can send json as (url-encoded) uri (string) parameter... which, we can map (back-end's) to json(/object)...

Comment: i'm not good at english sorry.
To explain it simply, when sending a get message from a tool such as postman, a json format like { "aaa":"bbb", "ccc":ddd"} is allowed, and empty data like { //empty } is also allowed. I think axios will throw an error if you pass it without braces. In summary, I want to put the body somehow when using the axios get() method. e.g) { ' ' }

Comment: The problem seems to be that there is no body when sending a Get message.

Comment: "Yes, you can send a request body with GET but it should not have any meaning." means: DON't ! ..at least not with HTTP <= 1.1(2014) ;)

Comment: neither with http2 (https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.8.1.2.6.p.2 , ff)

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to send data to the backend, it is standardized that the request should be a POST request instead of a GET request. That's why `axios` does not let you add a body to the request.

You can use the method `axios.post` to do so. For example,

```
axios.post(url, {
  "param1": "AA",
  "param2": "BB"
}
```

In Spring boot, however, you're required to change the `@GetMapping` to a `@PostMapping` and add a request body to the method arguments.

```
@PostMapping
public String myDefaultMethod(@RequestBody Object obj) {
    // ...
}
```